# foreach loop not working correctly with json encode Php

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I have multiple array (object inside array),But whnever i run foreach loop,its working 
one time only,What is the problem ? where i am wrong ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5cc6896028497b75f44cbf31
        }
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 5cc6896028497b75f44cbf32
        }
    ... 
}
```

Here is my code,But loop is working only time but i have many records(more than 100)

```
<?php
$final = json_decode($response);
$record=$final->data;
foreach($record as $re)
        {
            echo $re->_id;
        }
?>
```

Comment: where is data in your array response?

Comment: What does `$record` contain? Why don't you iterate over `$final`?

Comment: can you share your `$response`here?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your foreach loop:

```
<?php

$final = json_decode($response,true);

foreach($final as $key => $re)
   {
     echo $re['_id']. "<br>";
   }
```

Comment: you are basically saying array notation works - but object notation won't - where is that logic coming from ?